# Хранение параметров в базе данных

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть некоторые таблицы разных сущностей, например сотрудники, компании, марки автомобилей и т.д.

Есть некоторые параметры и их значения.
Названия параметров хранятся в таблице-справочнике. А их значения в таблице, связанной со справочником.

Значения параметров, в зависимости от их названия связываются с другими таблицами.

Например, если название параметра — имя сотрудника, то в значении хранится id сотрудника. Если — марка машины, то id марки.

Сейчас все эти варианты связей осуществляются в php скрипте, но это не совсем верно.

В Mysql запросе нельзя на лету подставлять имя таблицы. 
Как правильно спроектировать базу?

Answer (score 1):

> В Mysql запросе нельзя на лету подставлять имя таблицы.

Ну это не совсем так. Никто не мешает в рамках хранимой процедуры использовать динамический SQL (prepared statement).

Из описания не очень понятна **конечная** цель. Но сразу хочется обратить внимание на фразу "в зависимости от их названия". Вероятно, это означает связывание по строковому полю, что нехорошо. Попробуйте всё-таки работать с кодами параметров.

PS. Вообще подозреваю, что речь идёт о стандартной проблеме работы с EAV-атрибутами.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Речь идет о хранении кода или имени сущности в таблице с параметрами, чтобы можно было с ней связаться. 
Спасибо, за название, теперь понятно в какую сторону копать. Подскажите какие-нибудь лучшие практики в решении этих проблем.

Comment: Да нет их практически, лучших-то. EAV хорош немного для другого применения, либо в узких областях, а большинство "базистов" кроют его лаком, и небезосновательно. Думаю, иного способа кроме как начитаться того, что выдаст поисковик, и нет - нам-то трудно фильтровать базар, не зная до тонкостей Вашей предметной области и уже имеющихся наработок.

Comment: У меня все достаточно элементарно. Там, где хранятся параметры есть столбец table типа enum. По нему в php скрипте определяется таблица из которой вытягивать значение параметра по id. Это лишний запрос, который я бы хотел объединить с изначальным. А какие варианты кроме EAV существуют?

Comment: Я не понимаю, зачем потребовалось атрибуты **разных** сущностей сваливать в **одну** таблицу. Почему для каждой сущности не создать свою структуру таблиц для хранения атрибутов и мультиатрибутов. Вменяемая схема, полноценная система поддержания целостности, и никаких проблем вроде описанных. В чём профит-то?

Comment: Есть сущность. Для неё создаётся отдельная таблица. Есть её атрибуты. Они помещаются в эту таблицу. Либо в дополнительную таблицу,связанную с этой соотношением один-к-одному. Есть её мультиатрибуты со свободными значениями,которые помещаются каждый в свою таблицу,связанную с первой в соотношении один-ко-много. Есть её мультиатрибуты с фиксированным списком значений,для списка создаётся отдельная таблица-словарь,а для атрибута создаётся отдельная таблица,связанная с первой и со словарём в соотношении один-ко-много,образуя т.о. связь много-ко-много. И каждой сущности свои таблицы,кроме словарей.

Comment: Не очень понимаю как это разделить верно. Смотрите, есть таблица справочник в которой хранятся имена параметров. Этих параметров немного, около 100. Сами атрибуты относятся к одной сущности, которая имеет разные типы. Приведу пример, есть таблица с оплатами. Оплаты могут быть разных типов: оплата налогов, оплата интернета и т.д. В зависимости от типа, оплате соответствуют разные атрибуты, которые связываются с разными таблицами. Например оплате налогов соответствуют атрибуты расчетный квартал, номер счета, инн, а оплате интернета соответствуют имя провайдера, период и т.д.

Comment: Ну если очень хочется всё это хранить в одной таблице - храните в разреженной. C полями под все атрибуты. А в неиспользуемые поля для конкретной записи пишите Null.

Comment: Так в этом и вопрос, как связаться с разными таблицами в зависимости от столбца разряженной таблицы. Или если будут разные таблицы. Как организовать такой запрос на уровне  sql.

Comment: Почему _разными_? только что вроде договорились рассматривать вариант, что одна сущность - одна таблица, даже если у этой сущности несколько версий. Оплата? одна таблица оплат. А вот в зависимости от типа оплаты заполнены те или иные поля - для оплаты налога есть ИНН, но нет провайдера, а для оплаты Инета наоборот. А вот сумма оплаты заполнена у всех записей.

Comment: Это понятно, вопрос в том как это сделать на уровне одного запроса.
Как сделать саму выборку при такой организации. Как в самом запросе проверить из какой таблицы выбирать. Сейчас эта проверка делается в php. Сначала выбираем основные данные и имя таблицы, а потом вторым запросом подтягиваем значение из этой таблицы. Как объединить это в один запрос?

Comment: O_o ну таблица-то будет ОДНА.

Comment: Нет, у нас в любом случае будут таблицы с провайдерами, таблицы с различными видами налогов и т.д.
Эти таблицы не объединить, это совершенно разные сущности. И значение параметра провайдер при оплате ссылается на соответствующую строку в таблице провайдеры.

Comment: Ну тогда используйте динамику. Лучше на MySQL-сервере в рамках ХП.

Comment: Можно это реализовать без динамики? Как для этого нужно спроектировать базу, не храня в одной таблице сущности?

Comment: Так динамика будет на MySQL. А со стороны клиентского приложения будет тупо exec proc();

Comment: Это понятно, но насколько я понимаю, это плохое решение. Поэтому и возник вопрос, как сделать правильно

Comment: С учётом озвученных особенностей, требований и ограничений - имхо вполне нормальное решение. Вот оставить логику на клиенте - да, плохое, ну или во всяком случае хуже.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за советы! А как сделать запрос по уму и правильно, если сделать для каждой сущности параметров свою таблицу. Как решить задачу с подстановкой имени таблицы?